# TypeError: must be a unicode character, not str

Tags: python-3.x

This code worked with 2.7 but not with 3.5 - I understand that this has something do with being unicode compatible.

This is the code any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import array
import sys


ConstNoStudents = int(4)
Counter = int(0)
StudentMarkTest1 = array.array("Test 1", range(ConstNoStudents + 1))
StudentMarkTest2 = array.array("Test 2", range(ConstNoStudents + 1))
StudentName = []
StudentGender = []
input_value = raw_input

while Counter <4:
gender_value = int(0)
input_value = raw_input
Counter = Counter+1
StudentName.append (raw_input("Please Enter Student Name "))
print(StudentName)
while gender_value == 0:
    gender = raw_input("Please Enter Student Gender ")
    if gender == 'm' or gender == 'f' or gender =='M' or gender == 'F':
        StudentGender.append(gender)
        gender_value = gender_value+1

    StudentMarkTest1[Counter] = int(raw_input("Please Enter Mark for Test 1 "))
   StudentMarkTest2[Counter] = int(raw_input("Please Enter Mark for Test 2 "))

print (StudentName )
print (StudentGender)
print (StudentMarkTest1 )
print (StudentMarkTest2 )
```

Comment: What's the actual traceback?

Comment: For starters, there's no such thing as `raw_input` in Python 3. Beyond that, you'll need to provide input that produces the error and the actual contents of the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import array
import sys


ConstNoStudents = int(4)
Counter = int(0)
StudentMarkTest1 = array.array("d", range(ConstNoStudents + 1))
StudentMarkTest2 = array.array("d", range(ConstNoStudents + 1))
StudentName = []
StudentGender = []

while Counter <4:
  gender_value = int(0)
  Counter = Counter+1
  StudentName.append(input("Please Enter Student Name "))
  print(StudentName)
  while gender_value == 0:
    gender = input("Please Enter Student Gender ")
    if gender == 'm' or gender == 'f' or gender =='M' or gender == 'F':
      StudentGender.append(gender)
      gender_value = gender_value+1

    StudentMarkTest1[Counter] = int(input("Please Enter Mark for Test 1 "))
    StudentMarkTest2[Counter] = int(input("Please Enter Mark for Test 2 "))

print (StudentName)
print (StudentGender)
print (StudentMarkTest1)
print (StudentMarkTest2)
```

This is the Python3 version of your code, raw_input are now input.

Also, array.array's first parameter needs to be a character defining the data type.